# Python Distance Formula Calculator

Tags: python

My assignment is to make a distance calculator that finds the distance between two locations, and I chose to use Python.

I've put all the locations into coordinate points, but I need to know how to pick two of these by name, then apply the distance formula to them:

```
(sqrt ((x[2]-x[1])**2+(y[2]-[y1])**2)
```

Anyways, I don't need you to write the whole thing, just point me in the right direction.

```
fort sullivan= (22.2, 27.2)
Fort william and mary= (20.2, 23.4)
Battle of Bunker II= (20.6, 22)
Battle of Brandywine= (17.3, 18.3)
Battle of Yorktown= (17.2, 15.4)
Jamestown Settlement= (17.2, 14.6)
Fort Hancock=(18.1, 11.9)
Siege of Charleston=(10.2, 8.9)
Battle of Rice Boats=(14.1, 7.5)
Castillo de San Marcos=(14.8, 4.8)
Fort Defiance=(13.9, 12.3)
Lexington=(10.5, 20.2)
```

Comment: This currently isn't valid Python - just a text list.  What code do you have, and where are you running into problems with it? And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: you can find the `sqrt` function in the `math` module. and if this is homework please tag it as so.

Comment: Is there an 'intro to python' tag?  That might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to put them in a dictionary, like:

```
points = {
 'fort sullivan': (22.2, 27.2),
 'Fort william and mary': (20.2, 23.4)
}
```

and then select from the dictionary and run your thing

```
x = points['fort sullivan']
y = points['Fort william and mary']

# And then run math code
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a dict to store the tuples:

```
location = {}
location['fort sullivan'] = (22.2, 27.2)
location['Fort william and mary'] = (20.2, 23.4)
```

Or you can use the intializer syntax:

```
location = {
  'fort sullivan': (22.2, 27.2),
  'Fort william and mary': (20.2, 23.4)
}
```

Although you may well want to read the data in from a file.

Then you can write a distance function:

```
def dist(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2)**0.5
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
print dist(
  location['fort sullivan'], 
  location['Fort william and mary']
)
```